# progress bar does not close after loading main form java

Tags: java, swing

**Main Class is: excluding netbean hidden code
I am loading progress bar class first from main class and closing after completing progressbar in second class Name SplashScreen..**

```
package im;

import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

/**
 *
 * @author Ch. Virk
 */
public class frmMain extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    /**
     * Creates new form frmMain
     */
    public frmMain() {



       initComponents();


    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {

                SplashScreen execute;
                execute = new SplashScreen();
    }


}
```

---

**Second class:**

```
package im;

/**
 *
 * @author Ch. Virk
 */
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SplashScreen extends JWindow {

    static boolean isRegistered;
    private static final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar();
    private static SplashScreen execute;
    private static int count;
    private static Timer timer1;

    public SplashScreen() {

        Container container = getContentPane();
        container.setLayout(null);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder());
        panel.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
        panel.setBounds(10, 10, 348, 150);
        panel.setLayout(null);
        container.add(panel);

        JLabel label = new JLabel("Load Inventory Manager!");
        label.setFont(new Font("Verdana", Font.BOLD, 14));
        label.setBounds(85, 25, 280, 30);
        panel.add(label);

        progressBar.setMaximum(100);
        progressBar.setBounds(55, 180, 250, 15);
        container.add(progressBar);
        loadProgressBar();
        setSize(370, 215);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void loadProgressBar() {
        ActionListener al;
        al = new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                count++;

                progressBar.setValue(count);

                System.out.println(count);

                if (count == 100) {

                    createFrame();

                    execute.setVisible(false);//swapped this around with timer1.stop()
                    timer1.stop();

                }

            }
            private void createFrame() throws HeadlessException {
                frmMain mainForm = new frmMain();
                mainForm.setVisible(true);
            }



        };
        timer1 = new Timer(50, al);
        timer1.start();
    }





    public static void main(String[] args) {

        execute = new SplashScreen();
    }
}
```

**Error displaying :**
**Error is at this line code execute.setVisible(false);**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at im.SplashScreen$1.actionPerformed(SplashScreen.java:69)
    at javax.swing.Timer.fireActionPerformed(Timer.java:312)
    at javax.swing.Timer$DoPostEvent.run(Timer.java:244)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:251)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
```

Comment: You have a NullPointerException at line 69. What line is that?

Comment: SplashScreen execute does not seem to be initialized anywhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling a function inside your constructor (technically started by the timer thread), which is trying to use the variable `execute`, which isn't actually assigned until your constructor finishes executing. This is why the value is null, and you are getting an exception.

You could either redesign your class to avoid this sort of condition, or change the reference to refer to `SplashScreen.this` to refer to the containing instance of the outer class.

Answer (score 0):

Never use a variable with a function when it doesn't have anything assigned to it. This is what you have done, and it ends up with an error.